# In Jsoup, how to create an element without document?

Tags: java, jsoup

Now I use this to create an element

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->

        Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment("<ol></ol>");
        Elements ols=doc.getElementsByTag("ol");
        Element ol=ols.get(0);
```

But this is too complex, because I create many dom in the program, if every use three line to create an element, it is not convenient.

Can I create an element without using the document and elements?

like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var ol=$('<ol></ol>');
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use `Element`s constructor:

```
Element el = new Element(Tag.valueOf("ol"), "");
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: I don't know what to explain, i just used the constructor described in Jsoup javadoc http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#Element(org.jsoup.parser.Tag,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: @Alexy In example: "The Object class 'Elements' provides more than one ways. In this case ..." and so far.

Comment: This "valueOf" think made me have to google how to use a constructor, meh

Answer (score 5):

Since version 1.10.2, You can use `Element`'s constructor like this:

```
Element el = new Element("ol");
```

Constructor and Description:

`public Element(String tag)

  Create a new, standalone element.

Parameters:

  tag - tag name`